# How do I translate these weird UTF-8 "from" strings in e-mail context?

Tags: php, email, unicode, utf-8, decode

Receiving e-mails, I end up with "complete from strings" such as this one:

```
$test = '=?UTF-8?Q?Test=C3=B6p?= <no-reply@Testöp.tld>';
```

How do I get rid of the "=?UTF-8?" nonsense? Obviously I don't mean to just string-replace it, but to convert it properly to an actual UTF-8 string. It's supposed to be something like:

```
$test = 'Testöp <no-reply@Testöp.tld>';
```

I don't know why I get this in the first place, but I bet there is a simple function to do it somewhere in PHP.

***Note: It's not utf8_decode()! That one does nothing to that string!***

Comment: Is that the actual string or is it `%C3%B6`? If so that is urlencoded. Also how are you getting this into PHP?

Comment: @user3783243 I don't understand what you mean. Yes, it is the actual string. I didn't modify it in an attempt to be sneaky and make it harder for people to help me, if that's what you are suggesting. It comes from IMAP.

Comment: Can you show how you are making imap connection and getting the string? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-utf8.php might be what you need

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, that was it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. In the future I'd recommend holding off hostile comments until you know that is the commentator's prerogative. Knowing `It comes from IMAP.` was important to the question.

Comment: ... hostile comments?